# how to know the source table from a complex sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

PFB the query in which I want know the actual table where I can find these (**pin_ein,engineer_pin,transaction_date,EFFECTIVE_WEEK** )....

```
select count(1),pin_ein,engineer_pin,transaction_date,EFFECTIVE_WEEK from 
       (SELECT vw1.pin_ein, vw1.engineer_pin,
                               vw1.transaction_date, vw1.effective_week,
                               vw1.stores_tools_cost,
                               (vw1.stores_total_cost - vw1.stores_tools_cost
                               ) stores_total_cost_excl_tools,
                               vw1.item_count, vw1.stores_visit_count,
                               CASE
                                  WHEN vw1.stores_total_cost <
                                         5
                                     THEN vw1.stores_visit_count
                               END stores_low_cost_visit_count,
                               vw1.actual_ouc ouc, er.eng_name engineer_name,
                               CASE
                                  WHEN c.home_parked IS NOT NULL
                                     THEN c.home_parked
                                  ELSE 'N'
                               END home_parker,
                               CASE
                                  WHEN c.home_parked IS NOT NULL
                                     THEN c.commute_time
                                  ELSE -99
                               END commute_time,
                               vw1.stores_com_cost ---v9.3---
                          FROM (SELECT   pin_ein, engineer_pin, actual_ouc,
                                         transaction_date, effective_week,
                                         NVL
                                            (SUM
                                                (CASE
                                                    WHEN (   cow LIKE '%TOOL%'
                                                          OR cow LIKE
                                                                     '%TOOLE%'
                                                         )
                                                       THEN transaction_value
                                                 END
                                                ),
                                             0
                                            ) stores_tools_cost,
                                         SUM
                                            (transaction_value
                                            ) stores_total_cost,
                                         SUM (transaction_quantity)
                                                                   item_count,
                                         COUNT
                                            (DISTINCT sta_code
                                            ) stores_visit_count,
                                         NVL
                                            (SUM
                                                (CASE
                                                    WHEN cow in (SELECT cow FROM orbit_odw.stores_cow_ref)
                                                       THEN transaction_value
                                                 END
                                                ),
                                             0
                                            ) stores_com_cost     ---v9.3---
                                    FROM orbit_odw.stores_transaction_dtls
                                   WHERE effective_week BETWEEN 201543
                                                            AND 201610
                                     /***Ver 6.0---last 13 weeks data to be considered***/
                                     AND transaction_date
                                            BETWEEN to_date('19-10-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')
                                                AND to_date('06-03-2016','dd-mm-yyyy')
                                /***Ver 6.0---last 13 weeks data to be considered***/
                                GROUP BY pin_ein,
                                         engineer_pin,
                                         actual_ouc,
                                         transaction_date,
                                         effective_week) vw1,
                               (SELECT *
                                  FROM orbit_odw.dim_wms_rmdm
                                 WHERE current_status = 1) er,
                               (SELECT engineer_ein, commute_time,
                                       home_parked
                                  FROM orbit_odw.eng_parking_at_home_dtls
                                 WHERE rec_end_date > SYSDATE
                                   AND home_parked = 'Y') c
                         WHERE TO_CHAR (vw1.pin_ein) = er.ein
                           AND vw1.pin_ein = c.engineer_ein(+))  group by pin_ein,engineer_pin,transaction_date,EFFECTIVE_WEEK having count(1)>1;
```

Please help..
**thanks in advance**

Comment: You cant,unless you search in each table`s definition

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: The secret to figuring this out is to figure out how the subquery with the alias `vw1.` works. It looks like that's an aggregate of your `stores_transaction_dlts` table. Your query definitely has enough alias annotation to figure this out definitively.

Comment: You need a SQL parser for that, and then you need to write quite a bit of code on top of it to "understand" the query the way the RDBMS does. In the end it may not be even possible, because not all columns have a table source (e.g. computed columns) or multiple table sources (e.g. columns coming from `UNION ALL`).

Answer (score 1):

Basically if i understand your problem correctly. You need to understand from where your outer SELECT is fetching data. So there is a simple rule set used to get these data. Steps are as follows.

- Check the column output i.e in your case it's 
  pin_ein,engineer_pin,transaction_date,EFFECTIVE_WEEK
- Check the inline view or table from which your outer query is
  fetching the data. In your case its the only inline view you have
  used --> So bit easy to identify :P
- Now to identify how your inline view VW1 is populating data. In your
  case table orbit_odw.stores_transaction_dtls is used to populate the
  required fields.

Hope this much information is required. Also for simple queries you can always go to ALL_TAB_COLUMNS system tables to identify a table's column easily.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept the answeer if it helped you